# Python - Download images from website sudirectories (?)

Tags: image, web, url, download

Recently i used requests to download images using their url. i had a list of urls so it was easy.

This is the website https://cryptologos.cc/ i need images from

Its a bit different now because in order to see the images i want to download i need to "click" on each icon and then i am redirected to a webpage where the high res image i need is located.

So they are not all under the same url and i need to navigate somehow to each "subfolder" to get to the image i want.

I hope it makes sense.

How can i search through their site and automate this procedure?
I am a beginner obviously i need some advice on how to approach this

Comment: Do you own/work on that website?  Might need to provide more context about why you're trying to grab images from a particular site that enforces login and doesn't have a uniform url for their images.

Comment: no i dont won or work for the website. the images are for free you can download all of them manually by clicking on each symbol and then downloading the high res png. Is there a way to automate that? can it be done using requests or do i need some other kind of python library?

Comment: there is no login..what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry misread thought it was prompting you to login to see the high res image. Can you elaborate on the scenario you're trying to solve - are you trying to download all the images or specific ones based on some action of a user?  As a search could return multiple images.

Comment: if you click the link you will see what i am trying to achieve. the website presents you with a grid of icons and in order to download the highres for each one you have to click the icon and then download the high res. What i am trying to achieve is automate this for all available coins on the home page

Comment: Maybe google" python scrape image links" - and also share what you have tried and what you're having trouble with.